# Set values in matrix to 1 where index matches value

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have matrix:

```
[[0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2], [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2], [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2]]
```

and I would like to get matrix:

```
[[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]]
```

So if I try to explain this.. New matrix should have ones where index of row matches value. In first row all 0 should be 1 and all other values 0, in second row all 1 should be 1 and all other values 0 and so on...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily if you take advantage of broadcasting (assuming that `x` is a numpy array-- if not, you can convert it to one):

```
>>> np.arange(len(x))
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.arange(len(x))[:,None]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

The `[:None]` (or `[:np.newaxis]`) adda a singleton axis, so we have a 2D object of shape (3,1) instead of a 1D object of shape (1,).  Then we can compare:

```
>>> x == np.arange(len(x))[:,None]
array([[ True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

where the 0, 1, and 2 get compared with each element in each row.

After this, we have:

```
>>> (x == np.arange(len(x))[:,None]).astype(int)
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate is the way to go.

```
lst = [[0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2], [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2], [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2]]
lst = [[1 if i == j else 0 for j in l] for i, l in enumerate(lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work out:

```
matrix = [[0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2], [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2], [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,2]]

def fun(a,b):
    if a == b:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[i] = [fun(k,i) for k in matrix[i]]
```